# Add tooltip to d3 scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, scatter-plot

I've got the following scatter plot usind d3.js http://gkalliatakis.github.io./
and now I want to add tootltip of time (value of x axis) every time the mouse is over a triangle. I read lots of examples:
http://bl.ocks.org/weiglemc/6185069
but I was not able to modify them for my project.
Any thoughts?

Comment: In the future, it'll be much easier to answer your question if you tell us *why* you are unable to modify the examples to fit your code.  What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified your code to incorporate the tooltip from your example link.  The keys are this:

1.) Append the div tooltip to your html body (**note**, your html was malformed, it didn't have a body, I added those tags):

```
 var tooltip = d3.select('body')
      .append('div')
      .attr('class', 'tooltip')
      .style("opacity", 0);
```

2.) On mouseover/mouseout of your points update the div's html and show/hide the tooltip:

```
svg.selectAll(".point")
  .data(session_data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) { // show it and update html
    d3.select('.tooltip')
    tooltip.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", .9);
    tooltip.html(d.x)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
    tooltip.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  })
  .attr("class", "point")
  ...
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fimc64NNqQVLCXvTZlV7?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not able to figure out how to do it until I saw your modification.